# Not retrieving updated data from MySQL database - PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database

This is my code:

```
if($exp_minus_current > 0 AND $test_enabled == '0'){
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("UPDATE users SET test_enabled = '1' WHERE id = $user_id");
    $stmt->execute(); 
    $stmt->close();
    // SOME PHP CODE
}
```

When the test is submitted and the user is propagated to next page, the value of `test_enabled` is turning to "1" as desired!
But when the user again open the `test` page, it is again executing the code inside `if` curly braces.

Why it is not fetching new data and denying the `IF` condition second time???

Comment: well, you haven't shown how/where you set the $test_enabled option, nor how you "fetch new data", so we can't help you.

Comment: Need more code to be able to say for sure

Comment: `echo` out the values of `$exp_minus_current` and `$test_enabled` to verify they are the values you are expecting.  Better yet, use `var_dump()` to output the values.  You are setting the column `test_enabled` to '1'.  Setting this column in your MySQL table does not update your PHP variable `$test_enabled`.

Comment: @Marc B! your answer is correct ! I was NOT fetching the new data. It was using the same session variable which it fetched at the time of login. That's why when I was logging out and then logging in it was perfectly, but not otherwise. however, my lack of clarification in question answered it !!!:P